# How to use a JTextField in more than one class

Tags: java, swing, class, jtextfield, tic-tac-toe

I have 3 classes for Tic Tac Toe. 
     Class 1: This is the main class and it hold the button and such
     Class 2: The game itself calculates score and such
     Class 3: Displays the score from class 2

I am trying to get the score from class 2 and display it in class 3

```
`Class 2`
`public class TicTacEvent implements ItemListener, ActionListener, Runnable {
TicTac gui;
Thread playing;
ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("x.jpg");
ImageIcon b = new ImageIcon("o.jpg");
int clicks = 0;
int win = 0;
int winX = 0;
int winO = 0;
int tie = 0;
int[][] check = new int[3][3];

public TicTacEvent (TicTac in){
    gui = in;
    for (int row=0; row<=2; row++){
       for (int col=0; col<=2; col++){
           check[row][col]=0;
       }
   }
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
   String command = event.getActionCommand();

   if (command.equals("Play")) {
       startPlaying();
   }
   if (command.equals("1")) {
       b1();
   }
   if (command.equals("2")) {
       b2();
   }
   if (command.equals("3")) {
       b3();
   }
   if (command.equals("4")) {
       b4();
   }
   if (command.equals("5")) {
       b5();
   }
   if (command.equals("6")) {
       b6();
   }
   if (command.equals("7")) {
       b7();
   }
   if (command.equals("8")) {
       b8();
   }
   if (command.equals("9")) {
       b9();
   }
}

void b1() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[0][0].setIcon(a);
        check[0][0] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[0][0].setIcon(b);
        check[0][0] = 2;
    }
    winner();

}
void b2() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[0][1].setIcon(a);
        check[0][1] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[0][1].setIcon(b);
        check[0][1] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b3() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[0][2].setIcon(a);
        check[0][2] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[0][2].setIcon(b);
        check[0][2] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b4() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[1][0].setIcon(a);
        check[1][0] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[1][0].setIcon(b);
        check[1][0] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b5() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[1][1].setIcon(a);
        check[1][1] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[1][1].setIcon(b);
        check[1][1] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b6() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[1][2].setIcon(a);
        check[1][2] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[1][2].setIcon(b);
        check[1][2] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b7() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[2][0].setIcon(a);
        check[2][0] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[2][0].setIcon(b);
        check[2][0] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b8() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[2][1].setIcon(a);
        check[2][1] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[2][1].setIcon(b);
        check[2][1] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b9() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[2][2].setIcon(a);
        check[2][2] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[2][2].setIcon(b);
        check[2][2] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}

void winner() {
    /** Check rows for winner */

    for (int x=0; x<=2; x++){
        if ((check[x][0]==check[x][1])&&(check[x][0]==check[x][2])) {
            if (check[x][0]==1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner");
                winX = 1;
                System.out.println(Integer.toString(winX));
            } else if (check[x][0]==2){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O is the winner");
                winO = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Check columns for winner */
    for (int x=0; x<=2; x++){
        if ((check[0][x]==check[1][x])&&(check[0][x]==check[2][x])) {
            if (check[0][x]==1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner");
                winX = 1;

            } else if (check[0][x]==2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O is the winner");
                winO = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Check diagonals for winner */
    if (((check[0][0]==check[1][1])&&(check[0][0]==check[2][2]))||
            ((check[2][0]==check[1][1])&&(check[1][1]==check[0][2]))){
        if (check[1][1]==1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner");
            winX = 1;
        } else if (check[1][1]==2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O is the winner");
            winO = 1;
        }

    }

    /** Checks if the game is a tie */
    if ((clicks==9) && (win==0)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The game is a tie");
    }
}


void startPlaying() {
    playing = new Thread(this);
    playing.start();
    gui.play.setEnabled(false);
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

public void run() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

}

```
`Class 3`

`public class Score extends JFrame{
private JTextField xScore;
private JTextField oScore;
private JTextField tieScore;
private JButton reset;

public Score(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Score");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    FlowLayout score = new FlowLayout();
    frame.setLayout(score);
    xScore = new JTextField("X Wins: ");
    oScore = new JTextField("O Wins: ");
    tieScore = new JTextField("Ties: ");
    reset = new JButton("Reset");

    xScore.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 20);
    oScore.setBounds(0, 30, 100, 20);
    tieScore.setBounds(0, 60, 100, 20);

    frame.add(xScore);
    frame.add(oScore);
    frame.add(tieScore);
    frame.add(reset);

    frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in your previous similar question from 30 min ago:

- Use one JFrame. The other window should be a JDialog, although here a non-modal JDialog.
- Use a getter method to allow one class to get the score String from another class.
- The tricky part here that was not discussed as we did not have enough information at the time, is knowing when to pass the information to the Score JDialog. Here your main GUI should hold an instance of the Score JDialog, give this JDialog a setter method that would allow the main GUI to set the Score's score JTextField when the actual score changes.